# pandas/python Merge/concatenate related data of duplicate rows and add a new column to existing data frame

Tags: pandas, data-science

I am new to Pandas, and wanted your help with data slicing.

I have a dump of 10 million rows with duplicates. Please refer to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WedE7.png) for a sample of the rows with the steps I am looking to perform.

As you see in the image, the column for criteria "ABC" from Source 'UK' has 2 duplicate entries in the Trg column. I need help with:

1. Adding a concatenated new column "All Targets" as shown in image
2. Removing duplicates from above table so that only unique values without duplicates appear, as shown in step 2 in the image

Any help with this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please add sample data and code in your question

Comment: Kindly avoid images of data,no one can copy the data from image

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

PART 1:
First define a function that does what you want, than use apply method:

```
def my_func(grouped):
  all_target = grouped["Trg"].unique()
  grouped["target"] = ", ".join(all_target)
  return grouped

df1 = df.groupby("Criteria").apply(my_func)
#output:example with first 4 rows
    Criteria    Trg     target
0       ABC     DE      DE, FR
1       ABC     FR      DE, FR
2       DEF     UK      UK, FR
3       DEF     FR      UK, FR
```

PART 2:

```
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=["Criteria"])
```

I tried it only on first 4 rows so let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm glad! Don't forget to choose as best answer and also to upvote it so I can earn some reputation.